# Sourcemap in DevTools : change styles without losing the link to the SASS/Less file?

Tags: css, sass, less, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

When I use sourcemap with DevTools for CSS, is it possible to change styles without losing the link to the preprocessing file?

**More explanation**
Step 1 : I inspect an element, I see its style and I can see a link "global.scss", perfect.
Step 2 : I change a style (like a pixel under), and I lose my "global.scss" link, now is "global.css" and I need to reload my page!

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible, see https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors:

> Changes made in an external editor are not detected by DevTools until the Sources tab containing the associated source file regains focus. Also, manual editing of a CSS file generated by the Sass/LESS/other compiler will break the source map association until the page is reloaded

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue reported on chromium bug tracker, there you can follow the progress https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=257778#makechanges

**EDIT 1**

Finally this issue is currently resolved in Chrome Canary :-)

Link to confirmation: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=257778#c61

**EDIT 2**

Source map finally landed in Chrome